# Enterprise iOS developer program

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, enterprise

Is it necessary to register testers devices (UDID)? 
At a standard program each user device ID has to be added into dev program and build must be signed with proper provisioning profile containing the list of ID's. How it looks like in enterprise program.

Answer (score 1):

On enterprise you don't need to register any device, you can download from any device you want. 
Apple states that the maximum amount of devices are 500, but I don't if and how they check it.
But you need also to set on your html link to the file a proper link and a manifest.

Check this link to get started on how to distribute: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air